# Better option than display: block

Tags: css, display

So i wish to put an icon above an `h3` solely using css. Reason being that i don't wish to edit the html in a wordpress plugin.

So i decided to use pseudo element `::before` which displays the icon correctly but places it before the `h3` rather than above.

Adding `display:block` solved this issue until i decided to put a border around the icon, which then puts a border around the entire block, which is not what i want.

So i'm looking for better options if anyone can advise.

[image]

```css
h3.icon:before {
  font: normal normal normal 16px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0c1";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

<h3 class="icon" style="color: #000000;">Los Angeles</h3>
```

Comment: Can you show the html either? And how it looked before your changes?

Comment: I haven't changed the html with exception to adding the icon class so i could target it better.

Comment: Ok. But I need to see the html too to try to understand how to achieve your goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
h3.icon:before {
  font: normal normal normal 16px/1 FontAwesome;
  content: "\f0c1";
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  text-align:center;
  width:50px;
  margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<h3 class="icon" style="color: #000000;">Los Angeles</h3>
```

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve, do you want a border around the icon but not with all the extra padding in the block?

If that is the case try giving it a width and margin either side.

Comment: This did the trick .. Thanks for your help ! Greatly appreciated.